# Прорисовка карты с маркерами на WebGL

Tags: карты, webgl

Добрый день.
Возник следующий вопрос. Нужно прорисовывать автоматически пространство, где внизу будет находиться карта (сначала картинка, далее прорисованная с ландшафтом и т.д.), а в самом пространстве нужно прорисовать распределение газа (например у виде облаков разного цвета). С WebGL практически не знаком, посоветуйте фреймворк, с которым эту задачу можно легко решить. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В общем-то довольно-таки сложная задача) Я бы посоветовал использовать [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) т.к. более менее понятно, как что работает.

Готовых примеров можно по пальцам пересчитать, но они есть.
По сути вам нужно сделать генератор ландшафта (такие есть, например: [ручной генератор](http://cjcliffe.github.io/CubicVR.js/experiment/landscape_editor/landscape_edit_500m.html), и [автоматический](http://grahamweldon.com/posts/view/3d-terrain-generation-with-three-js)).

И каким-то образом прикрутить спрайты, примерно таким: http://www.mrdoob.com/lab/javascript/webgl/clouds/

Удачи!)